# How can I change the sprite of a new object in pygame every time it spawns?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game for my school project where fruits and unhealthy foods spawn from the top of the screen, I want to make the fruit and unhealthy food sprites change at random every time it spawns but have no clue how to implement it. I made two lists and placed the respective sprites into those lists, then I tried using the random.shuffle function to take a random sprite from that list and use it as the self image but I only get errors. This is the code so far:

```
import pygame
import random
import os

#make the sound and image directory a variable
img_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Images')
snd_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Sounds')

WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 720
FPS = 60

# define colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)
PURPLE = (160, 32, 240)

# Classes

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #This will create the image of the the player
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(basket_img, (250, 65))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (int(WIDTH / 2), int(HEIGHT - 100))
        
    def update(self):
        #This will be the movement of the player
        self.speedx = 0
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT] or keystate[pygame.K_a]:
            self.speedx = -9
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keystate[pygame.K_d]:
            self.speedx = 9
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
            
    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullet)
            
class Fruits(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = random.shuffle(fruits_list)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = 7
        
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        
class Health(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(health_img, (60, 60))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = 7
        
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        
class Money(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(money_img, (60, 60))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = 9
        
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        
class Gem(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(gem_img, (60, 60))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = 12
        
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        
            
class Bad_food(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = random.shuffle(bad_foods_list)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = 7
        
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20,40))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedy = -10
        
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        #kill if it moves off the top of the screen
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()

def spawn():
    if random.randint(1,3) == 1:
        f = Fruits()
        all_sprites.add(f)
        fruits.add(f)
    else:
        b = Bad_food()
        all_sprites.add(b)
        bad_food.add(b)
        
def health_spawn():
    h = Health()
    all_sprites.add(h)
    health_item.add(h)
    
def money_spawn():
    m = Money()
    all_sprites.add(m)
    money_item.add(m)
    
def gem_spawn():
    g = Gem()
    all_sprites.add(g)
    gem_item.add(g)

# initialize pygame and create window
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#this makes sure that the foods spawn in only every 2 seconds
SPAWN_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(SPAWN_EVENT, 2000)

#spawn a health item every 11 seconds
HEALTH_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 2
pygame.time.set_timer(HEALTH_EVENT, 11000)

#spawn a money item every 20 seconds
MONEY_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 3
pygame.time.set_timer(MONEY_EVENT, 20000)

#spawn a gem item every 60 seconds
GEM_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 4
pygame.time.set_timer(GEM_EVENT, 60000)

#load all of the graphics
background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'background.png')).convert()
background_rect = background.get_rect()
basket_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'basket.png')).convert()
apple_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'apple.png')).convert()
banana_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'banana.png')).convert()
cherry_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'cherry.png')).convert()
orange_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'orange.png')).convert()
pear_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'pear.png')).convert()
strawberry_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'strawberry.png')).convert()
chips_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'chips.png')).convert()
doughnut_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'doughnut.png')).convert()
hamburger_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'hamburger.png')).convert()
hotdog_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'hotdog.png')).convert()
icecream_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'icecream.png')).convert()
health_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'health.png')).convert()
money_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'money.png')).convert()
gem_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'gem.png')).convert()

#place all of the fruits and bad foods in a list
fruits_list = [apple_img, banana_img, cherry_img, orange_img, pear_img, strawberry_img]
bad_foods_list = [chips_img, doughnut_img, hamburger_img, hotdog_img, icecream_img]

# add sprites
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

#Group to keep the collectible items together
fruits = pygame.sprite.Group()
bad_food = pygame.sprite.Group()
health_item = pygame.sprite.Group()
money_item = pygame.sprite.Group()
gem_item = pygame.sprite.Group()

bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

#set the running total of the score to 0
score = 0

#set the health points to 5
health = 5

# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    # keep loop running at the right speed
    clock.tick(FPS)

    # Process input (events)
    if health == 0:
        running = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        #food spawning method
        if event.type == SPAWN_EVENT:
            spawn()
        if event.type == HEALTH_EVENT:
            health_spawn()
        if event.type == MONEY_EVENT:
            money_spawn()
        if event.type == GEM_EVENT:
            gem_spawn()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()

    # Update
    all_sprites.update()
    
    #Check to see if the basket collided with the food
    hits_fruits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, fruits, True)
    for hit in hits_fruits:
        score += 10
        print(f"score: {score} health: {health}")
        
    hits_bad_food = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, bad_food, True)
    for hit in hits_bad_food:
        score -= 10
        health -= 1
        print(f"score: {score} health: {health}")
        
    #check to see if the basket collided with the health item and give the health back unless over the max
    hits_health = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, health_item, True)
    for hit in hits_health:
        if health == 5:
            score += 20
            print(f"score: {score} health: {health}")
        else:
            health += 1
            print(f"score: {score} health: {health}")
            
    #Check to see if the basket collided with the money
    hits_money = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, money_item, True)
    for hit in hits_money:
        score += 100
        print(f"score: {score} health: {health}")
        
    #Check to see if the basket collided with the gem
    hits_gem = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, gem_item, True)
    for hit in hits_gem:
        score += 1000
        print(f"score: {score} health: {health}")
        
    bullet_hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(fruits, bullets, True, True)
    for hit in bullet_hits:
        score -= 10

    # Draw / render
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] of your code? The current code is way to long and includes things that are unnessecary for the question.

Answer (score 0):

[`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) is the wrong function for your task. `random.shuffle` shuffles an immutable sequence and returns a new shuffled list. You need to select a random element from this list. You can do that with [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

<s>`self.image = random.shuffle(fruits_list)`</s>

```py
self.image = random.choice(fruits_list)
```

<s>`self.image = random.shuffle(bad_foods_list)`</s>

```py
self.image = random.choice(bad_foods_list)
```